# trying to match a value in two arrays, if a matched value is present then output true

Tags: php, arrays, intersect, array-intersect

trying to match a value in two arrays, if a matched value is present then output true, thinking maybe the array_intersect function? very unsure! Any help is much appreciated!

Basically have two sql queries which i cant quite fit into this box! but they each return an array $staffExpertise and $moduleExpertise, but im very new to php and even more unfamiliar with the array intersect function so not too sure what to do from here!

```
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $staffExpertise = $row['expertise'];
    }

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $moduleExpertise = $row['expertise'];
    }

    $arrayIntersection = array_intersect($moduleExpertise,   $staffExpertise);

    if($arrayIntersection = ){

    }
```

Comment: Basically have two sql queries which i cant quite fit into this box! but they each return an array $staffExpertise and $moduleExpertise, but im very new to php and even more unfamiliar with the array intersect function so not too sure what to do from here!
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $staffExpertise = $row['expertise'];
        }

        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $moduleExpertise = $row['expertise'];
        }

        $arrayIntersection = array_intersect($moduleExpertise,   $staffExpertise);

        if($arrayIntersection = ){
            
        }

Comment: @FindlayMack Update your question with correct formatting.

Comment: Show us some of your attempted code or we can't help.

Comment: Ooh, edit your question instead of posting code in comments, its terrible to read!

Comment: @FindlayMack: why two SQL queries? Why not one `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @cegfault Perhaps the OP isn't as experienced with SQL to know how to successfully create `inner joins`.  But `inner join` is in best practice to get the hang of.

Comment: @DarylGill: because the OP did not post the SQL queries, I was asking in hopes finding out whether he doesn't know about `inner join`, or if there was some other reason why he isn't using them. If he doesn't know about them, that might be a better answer -- but I won't know if I don't ask

Comment: Yea i am familiar with inner joins, albeit to a ow level but didnt think that one would be appropriate as im not trying to store the information im just wanting to use it for a check in an if statement?

Answer (score 4):

Yes array intersect does it. Try something like this:

```
$names_1 = array("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David");
$names_2 = array("Alice", "Bruno");

$intersection = array_intersect($names_1, $names_2);

if(!empty($intersection) ){
    echo "The following item(s) exist in both arrays:"."<br>";
  foreach($intersection as $row){
      echo $row."<br>";
  }

}else{
echo "The arrays do not intersect";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much thats the slippery little line of code i was after!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
    if (in_array($Array1, $VarToCheck)) {
        $return = true;
    }elseif (in_array($Array2, $VarToCheck)){
    $return = true;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the problem is that as the $vartocheck is taken from two separate tables so i cant input them like that. For example im checking to see whether a lecturer has the correct module expertise to teach a module; the way i check is to see whether boththe moduleexpertise table and staffExpertise have a matched value. If that makes any sense?

Comment: That does. Check AaronSantos response, i believe that may do the trick!

Comment: Yea i think it does! Cheers for all the help!